# Terminal/Bash - Return until tab

Tags: regex, bash, terminal

I have this string;

```
4.0K /Server/mysql/backup/backup_mysql_ltr_20151006-131057.tar.gz
```

and I need only the `4.0K` returned, however obviously, this number could be anything. I believe there is a tab between the `K` and the `/Server`

Any ideas how it could be done. It'll be used in a terminal/bash command on Mac OS X and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<command that produces your output> | cut -f 1
```

And if that is not a tab between the `K` and the `/Server`, then

```
<command that produces your output> | cut -f 1 -d' '
```

Comment: Chose this one as the answer because simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to just use `awk`:

```
sz=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $1}')
```

as per the following transcript:

```
pax> string="4.0K /Server/blah_blah_blah.tar.gz"
pax> sz=$(echo "$string" | awk '{print $1}')
pax> echo $sz
4.0K
```

There are many other approaches using `cut`, `sed`, `grep -o` and so on<sup>(1)</sup> but I usually use `awk` because:

- it lends itself naturally to white-space separated fields; and
- it tends to allow for more powerful programming than the others.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Such as:

```
sz=$(echo "$string" | cut -f1)
sz=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/\t.*$//')
sz=$(echo "$string" | grep -o $'^[^\t]*')
```

and so on...

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for (1)'ing the alternate options too!

Answer (score 1):

```
s="4.0K /Server/mysql/backup/backup_mysql_ltr_20151006-131057.tar.gz"
x="${s// *}"
echo "$x"
```

Output:

```
4.0K
```

Comment: Maybe even `echo "${s//[[:space:]]*}"`, since the OP mentions tabs

Comment: Thank you for this usefull hint.

Comment: @Cyrus - is this solution compatible to all shells (sh, bash, ksh, csh, Tsh)?

Comment: @sras, it's unlikely but, since the question was tagged `bash`, it hardly matters. It's a good way to do it that doesn't involve kicking up another process.